# Update VirtualBox to install Extension Pack

Tags: updates, virtualbox, software-center

I installed Virtual Box via the Software Center on the latest fully updated Ubuntu 64bit.
I wanted to install the Extension Pack for VirtualBox but there is no version for my version of Virtual Box.
I have VirtualBox 4.3.10 installed (as seen in Help / About VirtualBox).

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html#extpack) are only extension packages for use with other versions downloadable.

Any suggestion what to do now? I don't want to deinstall VirtualBox and install the latest version over the website because this could be bad for future upgrades (could it? pretty new with Ubuntu).

Comment: Download [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Box provides old builds as well as the corresponding extension pack on the Download_Old_Builds page. Specifically you should check the [Download_Old_Builds_4_3 page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3).

You can use this direct link for version 4.3.10: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack