# I want to upgrade VirtualBox 4.3.10 to the latest version 4.3.28 so i can install the extention pack to enable USB 2 support

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

Do I need to first remove Vbox 4.3.10 and then purge and then get the latest 4.3.28 deb from Oracle? I am running 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to remove it. It is same package virtualbox-4.3.
Just install it and it will upgrade.

You can also add Virtualbox repository and it will be upgrade automatically.

Directions are at [Virtualbox site](http://virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: I found this AskUbuntu link which is what worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/510500/update-virtualbox-to-install-extension-pack?rq=1